# fs synchronization among desktops

Tags: btrfs, replication

I have several workstations (laptops and desktops).  I'd like to synchronize files among them such that each one is a mirror of the other.  I used to run an NFS server and share files out, but that only works if I am on the network.  I'd like to have access to my files, be able to make changes and when I connect to the network again, have the changes I've made be reflected to the other volumes and so on.

I'm considering btrfs or perhaps a clustered fs such as glusterfs or luster.  Are any of these good fits for frequently offline nodes?  It seems they'd work well if they were always online, but likely not work well for frequently offline.

Comment: I see glusterfs has self-heal functionality: http://www.tecmint.com/perform-self-heal-and-re-balance-operations-in-gluster-file-system/.  I will have to try this out to see if it will suit my needs.

Comment: I tested glusterfs with replication between 2 nodes and it seems to fit the bill.  When both nodes are online, replication occurs immediately, when not, it occurs when it is back online and during the next write.  I need to play with it more to see if this would suffice.

Comment: It seems with more complicated scenarios, I end up hanging my fuse mount point rendering it useless.  I wonder if there is a way to gracefully handle network connectivity issues or maybe my configuration is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually using git-annex.  I've been using it for over a year and it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe it seems more appropriate to use either a distributed revision control system (if they are all or mostly text files), or something like [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/).

rdiff-backup will copy the structure as you have locally to a server on the network and you'll have the same structure there. Roll-back is possible (based on delta's against the latest version) and you can purge those delta's etc.

Although snapshots in Btrfs have a similar rollback functionality, that doesn't give you the network facilities, although I think you could implement something like rdiff-backup on top of Btrfs (on the server) and rsync.

Comment: I've considering using a distributed revision control system, ie. git, mercurial, bazaar but am still not satisfied with that.  I could use send/receive facilities in btrfs to sync.  Perhaps, I'd need to read more about glusterfs, lustrefs to see if it would/could handle offline modes.